# how to use draggable in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, draggable

i'm trying to use draggable to drag header column in table like this

```
<thead>
  <draggable
    v-model="fields"
    :element="'tr'"
    :options="{ animation: 150 }"
  >
    <th class="" style="min-width: 59px"><Checkbox /></th>
    <th
      v-for="(field, index) in fields"
      :key="index"
      :style="field.type === 'date' ? 'text-align:center' : ''"
    >
      {{ field.text }}
    </th>
  </draggable>
</thead>
```

```
<script>
  import Checkbox from "./Checkbox.vue";
  import draggable from "vuedraggable";
  export default {
    components: {
      Checkbox,
      draggable,
    },
    props: {
      fields: Array,
      data: Array,
    },
```

But when i launch project, it show error

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
> whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
> computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
> "fields"
> Please help me Ths so much

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you defined your `fields: Array` and you are using it inside of your `v-for` there it is correct (if it's really an array).

But you have also used name `fields` inside of your `dragable v-model`. If you will rename this and change everything else inside of your code to the new name it should work out.

So in your case you send your data (`fields`) from your `parent.vue` to your `child.vue` and each time you select something from your `dragable` it will overwrite your `array` in the `v-for`.

*So little example:*
Array Fields: [Cat, Dog, Mouse] - You are selecting with v-model `fields` **Cat** - now your new Array Fields will be overwritten..

Hopefully it's now clear for you!

Comment: i'm trying to change that name but i dosen't working

Comment: still the same error? how do you change it.. could you update your code?

Comment: i change name and add same value but it can only change thead, but the data in tbody does not change with thead

Comment: please provide your current code or what would be even better if you create a sandbox or something else where I can check your code..